# Explain the output of the C pointer Challenge?

Tags: c, pointers

The output of the below program is `0 2` -  but i expect the output to be `<garbage value> 2`. Can somebody help explain why the output is `0 2`?

The question was asked at one of the leading world Engineering institutes in an entrance examination.

```
   #include<stdio.h>
    void f(int *p, int *q)
    {
      p = q;
     *p = 2;
    }
    int i = 0, j = 1;
    int main()
    {
      f(&i, &j);
      printf("%d %d \n", i, j);
      getchar();
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Why would you expect what you expect? Seems pretty straightforward to me. I have doubts on the leading role of the institution though...

Comment: Why are you expecting garbage value? Are not all the pointers well defined and used?

Comment: @usr why is `0` a garbage value? `int i = 0` and nothing has changed it - well defined.

Comment: @WeatherVane I ges usr means that if one expects a "garbage" value, why he won't consider `0` as one.

Comment: @EugeneSh. because "garbage value" would be a "fail" in the entrance exam.

Comment: @WeatherVane You mean if they expect "garbage value" answer and get the answer `0` instead? Yeah. It will be probably a fail. But I wouldn't trust a teacher expecting "garbage value" as an answer when UB is happening. (Generally, not in this specific case)

Comment: @EugeneSh. where is the UB? And the interviewer (not teacher) was expecting the answer 0, 2.

Comment: @WeatherVane I was expecting to trigger this question by writing *UB*.. So I added that thing in the parentheses :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. sorry you have lost me.

Comment: @WeatherVane Nevermind, I guess..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `p = q` allocation in function `f`  is limited to function body itself. Meaning that will not make change in memory location where `i` is pointing to. if you print value of `p` after `*p = 2;`in function `f` then value will be 2. But once function call is over allocation of p to q will not be transferred to i. You need `f(int **p, int *q)` type of parameter to return allocation of address of `q` to `p`.

Comment: **a)** `i` is not a pointer. **b)** `p` is a pointer; that means its "value" in function `f` will be an address. **c)** _"But once function call is over allocation of `p` to `q` will not be transferred to `i`"_...what does this even mean?  You're passing pointers to the function, so yes - the values of variables in `main` can be altered after the function exits...but `i` was never changed in the first place. **d)** Why in the world do you need a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: `i` is a variable. Suppose value of 'i' is stored to address 0xAAAA. Similarly  assume j is pointing addreess 0xBBBB. The address of `i` is passed to function `f`. Inside function `f`, `p` points to address 0xAAAA but after `p = q` statement `p` points to address of `q`, which is 0xBBBB. `*p = 2;` will store 2 at address 0xBBBB. Once function execution is over values of `i` will be taken from 0xAAAA, which is 0. And value of `j` will be taken from 0xBBBB which is 2. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes - that is all true given those hypothetical addresses.  However, I was referring to information in your answer. Where (a) is concerned, you mentioned, _"...change in memory location where `i` is pointing to..."_, implying `i` is a pointer. For (b): You also said, _"...if you print value of p...in function `f` then value will be 2..."_ - the "value" of `p` itself is an address, not 2. The value of what `p` _points to_, however, will be 2. (c) points out a part of your answer not really worded clearly. Aside: I don't mean to be harsh, I just believe the answer could be clearer.

Comment: @ManojKumarRai Thanks, your comment made my doubt clear.

Answer (score 2):

In the above code first value of i and j are:

```
i=0 j=1
```

Let's assume i is at some memory location 1000 and j is at 2000.

when you call the fucntion f():

```
p will be 1000 and q will be 2000.
```

then when you call p = q

```
p will be 2000 and j will be 2000.
```

then when you call *p=2

```
2 will be stored in location 2000 ie j = 2
```

so when you print i and j you get value of i and j which is 0 and 2.

Comment: *address is usually hex* Umm . . what?

Comment: address is usually represented by hexadecimal numbers. For example a 1MB ram has address from 00000H to FFFFFH.

Comment: Address is usually represented as *convenient* at the moment.

Comment: @WeatherVane that makes sense! OP can please you edit the answer to avoid confusion?

Comment: small typo to fix - "j will be 2000" should be "q will be 2000"

Comment: Yup i did change..tnx

Comment: Thanx @Arvindsinc2

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, this is pretty simple to follow.

You pass pointers to the variables `i` and `j` to function `f`.  Then, when you set pointer `p` to have the same address as pointer `q`, `p` will point to variable `j`.  You use the indirection operator to dereference `p` (access `j`), and change its value to 2.  Therefore, `i` is left at 0, making the result `0, 2`.

I don't see why there should be garbage values here.  All `p = q` does is make it impossible to access `i` inside the function using the available parameters as both `p` and `q` will point to `j`.

Therefore, `i` has *not changed at all* since it's original definition.  You could define it to be any arbitrary number, and it will stay the same back in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

p points to address of i, q points to address of j.

p=q implies p now points to where q points i.e. address of j.

*p=2 implies value stored at address pointed by p is now 2 i.e. j=2.

Hence i is what is was before i.e. i=0 and j=2.